# Is it possible to put an image on a Word document header and maintain it topmost?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, image-editing

We are putting an image on a Word document header and it is handled as a watermark standing at the back of other things.

Is there a way to maintain something in the header topmost?

Thanks.

See the example of what happens below (the header image is cut by the content image) no matter what you select on Format -> Arrange
[image]

Comment: I don't have ready access to Word, so I can't verify anything.  I don't want to post a speculative answer.  I believe what you're trying to do contradicts the way Word operates.  A header isn't intended for that purpose and I don't think you can do what you want using the header.  If you want an image in front of the document body, just make it a separate object instead of part of the header.

Comment: @fixer1234: I know what you mean but we heavily automate word and putting an element on lots of pages is way much slower that using the header :\

Comment: You might be able to make the image part of the document template as a separate object.

Comment: It looks as though there are 2 images in your header. Is your goal to have one of them (say, the right) be the height of the page content, to create a framelike layout such as is often used for webpages? Also do you want the white margins around all this, as shown in the image, or are you trying to fill the whole page? In both cases, it can be done, but I need more info before I post an answer.

Comment: My goal is to have a stamp on the header on top of anything in the document

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a way to maintain something in the header topmost?

Yes. Here are the instructions (pay attention to the parts I have marked in **bold**).

Note:

- This is for Word 2007 but it should be similar in Word 2010.

> If you have pictures, shapes, or other objects that are grouped or
>   stacked on top of each other, you can move objects or groups of
>   objects up or down within the stack one layer at a time, or you can
>   move them to the top or bottom of a stack in one move.
>
> 1. **Click the picture, shape, text box, or WordArt that you want to move up or down in the stack.**
>
>    Try to click a part of the object that
>      is not obscured by another object in the stack.
>
>    If you can’t select
>      the object that you want, you may need to move other objects that are
>      currently above it in the stack first.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    - **To move a picture, under Picture Tools, click the Format tab.**
>
>      [image: Picture Tools tab]
>    - To move a shape, text box, or WordArt, under Text Box Tools, click the Format tab.
>
>      [image: Drawing Tools Format tab image]
> 3. In the Arrange group, do one of the following:
>
>    - To bring an object one step closer to the front, click the arrow next to Bring to Front, and then click Bring Forward.
>    - **To bring an object to the front, click the arrow next to Bring to Front, and then click Bring to Front.**
>    - To send an object one step toward the back, click the arrow next to Send to Back, and then click Send Backward.
>    - To send an object to the back, click the arrow next to Send to Back, and then click Send to Back.

Source [Move a picture, shape, text box, or WordArt](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-a-picture-shape-text-box-or-WordArt-dab7e591-bd7b-4dbc-a8e9-7c90a8de3a1f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I made the question ambiguous. What I  really need is to put the content of the header topmost over the content of the document. I have an image on the header and another image on the body on the document. I need the header image over the document image.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia The answer is exactly the same. Select whatever you want to be in front and then bring it to the front. It doesn't matter if it is an image or text. If you can't see the text (because it is behind an image) then send the image to the back.

Comment: bring to front does nothing with the header image below the content image ... :S See my edit

Comment: I really don't know any more what you are trying to do and what is going wrong :/

Comment: I don't have ready access to Word, but I think the issue is that these layers operate within a major layout object.  So you can bring the picture to the front of the header, but that doesn't bring it in front of another layout object.  My recollection is that Word gives the document body precedence over headers and footers if the page layout results in overlapping.  The solution might be to just ensure that the top margin is adequate so that the header doesn't get covered by the body content.  Otherwise, make the image a separate object, not part of the header.

Comment: @fixer1234: thanks for the feedback, in fact the effect I need is to have the header over the content as the header is a kind of stamp. Do you know if that major layout object is available thru automation (macros)?

Comment: @fixer1234: by the way if you put an answer with the content of the comments we can talk in the right answer ;)